# Extracting img url from a website using python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This code gets images from a website , but for some i am getting `list index out of range` which has no img data. How to overcome that. Have used many try excepts, Is there any way other than try-except

url =

`https://www.redbook.com.au/cars/details/2016-isuzu-d-max-ls-u-high-ride-auto-4x2-my155/SPOT-ITM-445820/`

For whose there are no image i'm getting this error

`list index out of range`

like for this url

`https://www.redbook.com.au/cars/details/2019-audi-s3-auto-quattro-my19/SPOT-ITM-522293/`

How to skip this situation

code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
import html
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import json

cars = []  # gobal array for storing each car_data object



with open('url.txt') as f:

    # read file without newlines

    urls = f.read().splitlines()



for url in urls:

    car_data = {}  # use it as a local variable
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')



    img_url = tree.xpath('//ul/li/a/img/@src')[0]
    img_url = str(img_url)
    img_url = img_url + '0'
    car_data['image_url'] = img_url
    script = soup.find('script', text=re.compile('CsnInsights.metaData'))
    jsonData = \
    json.loads(script.text.split('CsnInsights.metaData = ')[-1].rsplit(';', 1)[0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply [`EAFP` principle](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) and handle the [`IndexError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError), which is the built-in exception thrown in this case:

```
try:
    img_url = str(tree.xpath('//ul/li/a/img/@src')[0]) + '0'
except IndexError:
    img_url = ''
```

Note that I am using an empty string as an image url value when it is not available (failed to be extracted from HTML), but depending on your situation you can choose another value - e.g. `None`, or use `continue` to entirely skip processing this item.